# Angularjs. How to make input field look like 253.3445.9621?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

How can i make a phone input field looking like "253.3445.9621" on input.
And how to make only numbers inputting possible?

I want that the value in model(or correct to say scope? confuse them with each other( ) is equal to "25334459621", but on input for user it should be with .
I'm using angular and bootstrap.

```
<input id="contactn" name="contactn" placeholder="" class="input" type="text"
                           ng-model="data.contact">
```

Thank you!

Comment: As I understand, you want to format the display of the value inside the input[text] as 253.3445.9621 and keep the model as 25334459621. You should have a look at ui-mask from AngularUI (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)! You can then add the directive: ui-mask="999.9999.9999" and it will only format the value for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use directive:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test" separator="number" />
```

**directive**

```
app.directive('separator', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;


            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(a) {
              return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });


            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
              var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
              elem.val( $filter('number')(plainNumber) );
              return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

See <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/704/)</kbd>

Image:

[image]

Comment: It does not support the requested format of 999.999.9999. And i can put only 0s, it stops at 2 characters.

Comment: @jpmorin  Because I use commas instead. You can easy replace, see the image

Comment: But if i press 1 and then constantly pres letter s or other letter i get "1s" once i press s disapears, another press it apeears again in input field, but not in scope variable. Why is it so and how to fix it?  http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/6230/uw92.png

Comment: well, I gave the direction how it should look like. You would play with my Fiddle and achieve the exact goal. If you feel that my answer is helpfulness , hope someone will give you better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

[Angular UI-Mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils#mask) is the best solution. It's based on the jQuery Mask plugin that has been pretty well vetted:

Answer (score 0):

You should research creating your own custom [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)  that uses [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) for restricting the input to valid phone number format. You can strip out the '.' within the directive after validating format.